# Keep text in BasicTextField on back navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation, android-jetpack-compose-text

I have a BasicTextField in my jetpack compose function. When i click(user has input some text into the textfield by now) on a button to navigate to another composable in my NavHost, and from that new view click on back to the composable which i came from which has the textfield, the textfield is empty. I want to keep the text that the user typed in before navigating, but I can't figure it out how. Have looked here but found no answer.

Suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
@Composable
fun SearchBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onSearch: (String) -> Unit = {}
) {
    var text by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    Box(modifier = modifier) {
        BasicTextField(
            value = text,
            onValueChange = {
                text = it
                onSearch(it)
            },
            maxLines = 1,
            singleLine = true,
            textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.Black),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .shadow(5.dp, CircleShape)
                .background(Color.White, CircleShape)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Save it in a suitably-scoped viewmodel. `remember()` only remembers until your composition gets disposed, which will happen when you navigate. Alternatively, you could consider `rememberSaveable()`, if this is data that you wish to have survive a configuration change or short-term process termination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`remember` saves the value over [recomposition](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#recomposition) (i.e., when your state changes, your composable automatically recomposes with the new state).

As per the [Restore UI State guide](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#restore-ui-state), you can replace `remember` with [`rememberSaveable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/saveable/package-summary#rememberSaveable(kotlin.Array,androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.Saver,kotlin.String,kotlin.Function0)) to save your state across:

- Configuration changes
- Process death and recreation
- Your composable being put on the `NavHost` back stack

As well as any other case where your `SearchBar` could be removed from composition and then re-added (such as if you were using in [Accompanist's Pager](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/) or in a `LazyColumn` or `LazyRow`).

```
var text by rememberSaveable {
    mutableStateOf("")
}
```